# <activeByDefault/> doesn't work when another profile triggered

Tags: maven

I have profiles look like this.

```xml
    <profile>
      <id>active-by-default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
          <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
          <version>${version.org.mongodb}</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>java8</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>(,1.8]</jdk>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <libs>
                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                <lib>${java.home}/lib/jce.jar</lib>
                <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
              </libs>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>java9</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>[1.9,)</jdk>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <libs>
                <lib>${java.home}/jmods/java.base.jmod</lib>
              </libs>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

Those two `java-` profiles are for ProGuard.
And I found the `active-by-default` profile doesn't work even with no profiles specified.

I found it works when I remove one of those `java-` profile which meets my current JDK version.

Is this intended?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the documented behaviour :

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html